# Save changes in annotated Pdf to the original file

Tags: 16.04, pdf, document

I'm annotating a pdf in `Document Viewer`. After making some changes in pdf I want to save it.

But there is only save a copy option there. So everytime I've to save new copy and delete older one. Is there any solution to it?